# Center of a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

so what I need to do is to tell the user to type values for a matrix and print the center of this one. I've this code but I´m missing that.

```
import sys
reng = int(input('row: '))
column = int(input('column: '))
matrix = []
suma = 0
lista = []

if reng < 0 or column < 0:
    print('NOT VALID')
    sys.exit()

else:
    for i in range(reng):
        matrix.append([0]*column)

    for j in range(reng):
        for k in range(column):
            matrix[j][k] = int(input('enter an integer: '))
print(matrix)
```

Comment: You mean the center element? `matrix[reng//2][column//2]`

Comment: Yup, for example:

Comment: [[1,2,3]] [[4,5,6]] [[7,8,9]]

Comment: Print number "5"

Comment: GZeuS: @tevemadar has given you the answer…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(matrix[reng//2][column//2])
```

will print you the exact middle element of an "odd*odd" matrix. `//` is integer division, so for example `3//2` is `1`, which really is the middle one of possible indices `0`, `1`, `2`. Even numbers have a middle-pair, and division produces the higher one (like in case of 4: `4//2` is `2`, which is the "upper middle" element of the possible indices `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`).

Comment: Thank very much tevemadar! Really helpful :D